# pieChart animation

Tags: animation, core-plot, pie-chart, fill

I have draw a pieChart with CorePlot,and I want to fill each piece of the pieChart with animation.The point is Core-Plot doesn't has a animation on CPTPieChart.So how should I add a fill animation to the pieChart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All visible parts of a Core Plot graph are drawn in Core Animation layers. All of the standard animations are available to you. Many Core Plot-specific properties are animatable as well. There is a list of animatable properties in the [Core Plot docs](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/group__animation.html). You can also use the `CPTAnimation` class to animate nearly any property, including those that are not supported by Core Animation.